# How to increase speed of video playback within Python using openCV

Tags: python, performance, opencv, video-capture

I am writing a program that draws a line on a video where the first pixels of the railing are encountered, my problem is that the video playback is sluggish.

[image]
Screenshot for reference of what the video looks like. During the video the camera is moved closer but because of the slow speed, I have to wait a few minutes to see the change, but when filming took place, it was moved every few seconds.

I assume the issue is the fact that the for loops are operating on every single frame of the video but I am not sure.

What solution could I implement to speed up my program?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    canny = cv2.Canny(frame, 85, 255)
    height, width = canny.shape

    first_black_array = []

    for x in range(width):
        first_black_pixel_found = 0
        for y in range(height):
            if first_black_pixel_found == 0:
                if canny[y,x] == 255:
                    first_black_array.append(height - y)
                    first_black_pixel_found = 1
                    cv2.line(frame,(x,y),(x,y),(0,255,0),1)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem...

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
         if canny[y,x] == 255:
```

Numpy.argmax is the solution...

```
for x in range(width-1):
    # Slice the relevant column from the image
    # The image 'column' is a tall skinny image, only 1px thick
    column = np.array(canny[:,x:x+1])
    # Use numpy to find the first non-zero value
    railPoint = np.argmax(column)
```

Full Code:

```
import cv2, numpy as np, time
# Get start time
start = time.time()
# Read in the image
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/rail.jpg')[40:,10:-10]
# Canny filter
canny = cv2.Canny(img, 85, 255)
# Get height and width
height, width = canny.shape
# Create list to store rail points
railPoints = []
# Iterate though each column in the image
for position in range(width-1):
    # Slice the relevant column from the image
    # The image 'column' is a tall skinny image, only 1px thick
    column = np.array(canny[:,position:position+1])
    # Use numpy to find the first non-zero value
    railPoint = np.argmax(column)
    # Add the railPoint to the list of rail points
    railPoints.append(railPoint)
    # Draw a circle on the image
    cv2.circle(img, (position, railPoint), 1, (123,234,123), 2)
cv2.imshow('img', img)                      
k = cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(time.time() - start)
```

My solution using Numpy took 6ms and your solution took 266ms.
[image: rail output]